# Set Build Directory for ASP.NET Core Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.Net Core (.NET Framework) Project added to my solution and also some .NET 4.5.2 Class Libraries.

Usally I use an container for IoC/DI and haven't to reference the infrastructure libraries to the WebAPI project. So I set on all the projects the same Output directories and build it. This is also needed to create a Setup with all my DLLs inside.

In standard .NET Projects I use `../../build/` for all the projects and get all the DLLs inside it. In the Core project I also added this directory in the Outputpath XML-Node. Unfortunatly it creates on build the following directory structure:

```
build/
  My.Infrastructure.dll
  My.Infrastructure.xml
  My.Core.dll
  My.Core.xml
  My.WebAPI/
    bin/
      Debug/
        net452/
          win7-x64/
            ..dlls..
```

Is there a way to configure the output path like the one in the old projects?

Comment: Dunno if you can change the build directory though, but you can define pre/post script commands in your project.json in the "scripts" section, like this https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/samples/MusicStore/project.json#L74-L76. Just in your case you'd likely want to use "postcompile" trigger. you can even execute multiple commands, when you turn the "postcompile" from string to an array `["command1", "command2", "command3"]`.